# return all points within 100 miles of bounding box in postgis

Tags: sql, postgis

I'm still learning postgis and need some help.  I have 2 tables, cities and attractions.  I want to return all attractions within X miles of given city.  These are my own tables, so I can set them up any way that is best for this.  Right now, my attractions have a geom POINT column with srid 4326 which is lat/lng. My cities table has a geom BOUNDING BOX (POLYGON) column which encloses the city boundaries. I used ST_MakeEnvelope to fill in that column, also 4326.

I've looked at ST_Expand and ST_DWithin, but I can't seem to figure out how to both search the attractions table and expand the box out, and also return miles.

Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to return all attractions within X miles of given city

that's easy with [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM attractions AS a
JOIN cities AS c
WHERE ST_DWithin(c.geom::geography, a.geom::geography, X*1604);
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you Evan!   One change -  use ON instead of WHERE and it works perfectly!